# Trying to return to previous page with javascript + html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

UPDATE

I solved the problem, it was quite silly, I named the "id" wrong. It was: id="groups_menu_left" when it actually is: id="especies_menu_left".
Sorry to waste your guys's time.

When I hit the button "Voltar" which means "Back" it isn't going back, can anyone help me?
My application is basically a database for shelters, so when people want to adopt a new pet, they can look for the options various shelters have. When choosing the "Species" it shows all the animals in that category, and when you like an animal, you can click on it for more info. But if a person didn't like the specific info for some reason, they can return to look for more animals, and that's where the button "Voltar" is helpful, but it's not working. When I click on it it doesn't do anything. It doesn't show an error when debugging, so my guess is that I'm missing something in the code.

```js
(function($) {

  $.extend({

    route: function(path) {

      var previousUrl = window.location.hash.slice(1);
      window.location.hash = '#' + path;

      var pathArray = path.split('/');

      $('div[id^="template_"]').hide();
      $('button[id^="menu_"]').hide();

      var routes = [{
          id: 1,
          name: 'index',
          regex: '(index)'
        }, // index
        {
          id: 2,
          name: 'register',
          regex: '(register)'
        }, // register
        {
          id: 3,
          name: 'especies',
          regex: '(especies)'
        }, // especies
        {
          id: 4,
          name: 'especie_show',
          regex: '(especie).*?(\\d+)'
        }, // especie/{:id}
        {
          id: 5,
          name: 'animal_show',
          regex: '(animal).*?(\\d+)$'
        }, // animal/{:id}

      ];

      var route = 0;
      var template = null;

      $.each(routes, function() {
        var test = new RegExp(this.regex);

        if (test.test(path)) {
          route = this.id;
          template = this.name;
        }
      });

      //Logout button
      $('#' + template + '_menu_logout').on('click', function() {
        removeToken('token');
      });

      switch (template) {

        case 'index':
          break;

        case 'register':
          break;

        case 'especies':
          setButton('left', template, 'index', 'redirect', null);

          $.api.getRecords('especie', null, getToken('token'), populateEspeciesTable);
          break;


        case 'especie_show':
          setButton('left', template, 'especies', 'redirect', null);
          setButton('right', template, 'especie/' + pathArray[1] + '/edit', 'redirect', null);


          var params = 'filter=id_especie%3D' + pathArray[1] + '&fields=nome_especie';
          $.api.getRecords('especie', params, getToken('token'), populateEspecieShowName);

          params = 'filter=especie_id_especie%3D' + pathArray[1] + '&fields=nome_animal, notas_animal, foto_animal';
          $.api.getRecords('animal', params, getToken('token'), populateEspecieTable);

          break;

        case 'animal_show':
          var animalId = $('#id_animal').val();

          setButton('left', template, 'especie/' + animalId, 'redirect', null);
          setButton('right', template, 'animal/' + pathArray[1] + '/edit', 'redirect', null);

          var params = 'filter=id_animal%3D' + pathArray[1] + '&fields=nome_animal';
          $.api.getRecords('animal/' + pathArray[1], null, getToken('token'), populateAnimal);

          var urlParts = previousUrl.split('/');
          $('#id_animal').val(urlParts[1]);

          break;

      }

      $('#template_' + template).show();
    }
  });


  function setButton(button, page, url, type, func) {
    switch (type) {
      case 'redirect':
        $('#' + page + '_menu_' + button).off().on('click', function() {
          $.route(url);
        });
        break;
    }
  }

}(jQuery));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="template_especies">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top df-nav cen col-md-12" role="navigation" style="">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav" style="width: 100%">
      <li style="float: none; display: inline-block; position: relative; text-align: center">
        <a href="#index"><img src="img/icone_ap.png" height="47"></a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <div class="row vert-offset-top-30"></div>
  <div class="col-md-2"></div>
  <div class="col-md-8">
    <img src="img/cao.jpg" width="150" hspace="20"> <img src="img/gato.jpg" width="150">
    <table class="table" id="table_especies">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
  <footer>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav" style="width: 100%">
      <li class="pull-left"><button type="button" id="groups_menu_left" class="btn btn-default btn-menu">Voltar</button></li>
      <li class="pull-left"><button type="button" id="groups_menu_logout" class="btn btn-default btn-menu-logout">Sair</button></li>
    </ul>
  </footer>
  <div class="col-md-2"></div>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: I edited your question to make the code snippet runnable, however it doesn't seem to show much, probably because the images don't load.

Comment: Can you include more or less code so that someone can help identify the problem?

Comment: It uses data from a database, I don't know a way to make runnable :/

Answer (score 3):

Try using [`window.history.back();`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_his_back.asp) and attaching it to the element with `onclick="window.history.back();`

You can try it below.

```html
<li class="pull-left">
  <button type="button" onclick="window.history.back();" id="groups_menu_left" class="btn btn-default btn-menu" >Voltar</button>
</li>
```

**UPDATE:** I don't know if I understand your problem but you can try:

```
<li class="pull-left">
  <a href="../"><button type="button" id="groups_menu_left" class="btn btn-default btn-menu" >Voltar</button></a>
</li>
```

Comment: It changes the page on the browser (I'm testing using chrome) but it doesn't update.

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't update"? Also, could you post your error?

Comment: I press the button "voltar" I see in the browser the change from
"http://localhost/files/Amigos%20Peludos/index.html#especie/1"
to
"http://localhost/files/Amigos%20Peludos/index.html#especies"

But it doesn't go the page "especies" it stays on "especie/1". I don't know about building the app, if it will update, but so far, it isn't.
It's not showing any error, just not updating. Do you know if there's a way to kinda refresh the page?

Comment: Shoul I put something inside ".../"? It goes all the way back to localhost/files.

Comment: I think you used three dots. It's supposed to be two. It's a way to tell the browser to move up one directory, from `parent/child` to `parent`